# pdf-lib Search text and replace with image

Tags: node.js

---

- To replace a digital signature in a PDF with text using Node.js, you can use a library like pdf-lib
- I have one pdf file like offer_letter.pdf
- this pdf file one text is owner_sign
- now this pdf file text replace with sign Image

  ```
        async function modifyPdf() {
            try {
                const { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb } = require('pdf-lib');

                const fs = require("fs");
                const path = require("path");

                // Fetch an existing PDF document
                const url = "mypdfurl";

                // Load the PDF file
                const pdfBytes = fs.readFileSync('hr.pdf');

                // Load the signature image
                const signatureImageBytes = fs.readFileSync('sign.png');
                const textToRemove = "owner_sign";
                // Create a new PDF document
                const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);

                // Get the first page of the document
                const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();

                for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {

                    const signatureImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(signatureImageBytes);
                    const { width, height } = signatureImage.scale(0.5);
                    const signaturePosition = { x: 350, y: 220 };
                    // page.drawText(textToRemove, {
                    //   x:  signaturePosition.x,
                    //   y: signaturePosition.y,
                    //   font: await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica),
                    // });
                    page.drawImage(signatureImage, {
                        x: signaturePosition.x,
                        y: signaturePosition.y,
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                    });
                }


                // Save the modified PDF document
                const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
                fs.writeFileSync('modified.pdf', modifiedPdfBytes);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        modifyPdf();
  ```

  I have one pdf file like offer_letter.pdf

  this pdf file one text is owner_sign

  now this pdf file text replace with sign Image

Answer (score 2):

Finally done Existing PDF Add sign with proper position

```
enter code here

const pdfjs = require('pdfjs-dist');
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib');
const fs = require("fs");
const nodeFetch = require("node-fetch");
let fileURL = "";
let signURL = ""
const printSignature = async () => {
 const response = await nodeFetch(fileURL);
 const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
 const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);

 const responseImgFile = await nodeFetch(signURL);
 const arrayImgBuffer = await responseImgFile.arrayBuffer();
 const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayImgBuffer);

 const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(fileBuffer);
 const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();

 let pageArra = await getPositionV2(pages.length,fileBuffer);
 const signatureImageBytes = imageBuffer ? imageBuffer : 
 fs.readFileSync('sign.png');

 for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    const page = pages[i]
    const signatureImage = await pdfDoc.embedPng(signatureImageBytes);
    // const { width, height } = signatureImage.scale(0.7);
    const xAndYTranform = pageArra.filter((pageArr) => pageArr.page === i).map(pg => pg.transform).flat()
    if (xAndYTranform.length) {
        page.drawImage(signatureImage, {
        x: xAndYTranform[4] +2,
        y: xAndYTranform[5] -2,
        width:220,
        height:35
        })
    }
 }
 const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
 fs.writeFileSync('sugnPDF.pdf', modifiedPdfBytes);
}

async function getPositionV2(pageLength,fileBuffer) {
 const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument(fileBuffer).promise;
 const result = Array.apply(null, Array(pageLength)).map(function (_, index) {
  return pdf.getPage(index + 1).then(function (page) {
   return page.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
    const transform = textContent.items
     .map(function (item) {
       if (
         item.str.includes("Signature of person responsible for deduction")
       ) {
         return item.transform;
       }
     })
     .filter((item) => item !== undefined)
     .flat();
   return { page: index, transform }
  });
 });
});
return await Promise.all(result)
}


printSignature();
```

Comment: Thanks HEMANT, Your response has been very helpful. Though I found that in my case, there's no need to use `const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);`. It turns out that pdfjs requires a unit8array instead of a buffer.